# odp.net tracing

Tags: oracle, odp.net

How can i enable tracing in a odp.net client from the connection string? Just adding the parameters traceFileName, TraceLevel and TraceOption ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some researching, I've found that ODP.net can be configured via web.config olny in version 11 and above. For previos versiones of ODP.Net, the only way is using the windows registry

Comment: Yep: "ODP.NET Configuration File Support is only available for 11.1.0.6.0 and later." http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/InstallODP.htm#BABCBFDJ

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You'll need a registry or XML fix.

But you can emit `ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE=true` right after logon, either in your application or in `AFTER LOGON` trigger.

`ODP.NET` does exactly the same: it looks into registry and executes this statement.

Answer (score 0):

A few tips for those finding this from Google:

Note that the trace will default to go in the root of the C drive. For Windows 7 and later, this requires administrator privilege or it will just fail silently. So either make sure your app is running as administrator or that you change the path of the file.

Also note, that if you want to trace ODP.NET fully managed, you need to put the settings inside the app or web config file, not the registry, AND the settings for TraceLevel are different (1 through 7).

And finally, when tracing unmanaged ODP.NET remember that there is a separate WOW registry node for 32 bit Windows. If your app is 32 bit, don't accidentally set it under the 64 bit portion of the registry.